# How can I create a brush that picks from several shapes randomly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I would like to create a brush that **randomly chooses a shape** from about 5 shapes **that I provide**. Something like in the image below - **the red, green, purple and yellow shapes** (ignore the planets and other stuff).

Any help on how I can achieve this, please?

[image: Example brush result]

Comment: Photoshop doesn't have this functionality. A free Krita has, however: https://docs.krita.org/en/tutorials/krita-brush-tips/animated_brushes.html

Comment: Do you just want individual stamps, or a continuous drawing with that shape (kind of "smearing" the shape on it being held down rather than doing multiple "stamps" of the image)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKEb2to48NA might be useful.

Comment: Hmm... someone brought this up at https://www.reddit.com/r/AdobeIllustrator/comments/5fmmrq/question_creating_a_random_pattern_or_brush_w/ three years ago and apparently there's a script to randomly pick brushes (http://egypt.urnash.com/blog/2015/04/04/illustrator-brush-munger/) and the Stipplism plugin (https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/stipplism) but nothing native.

Comment: https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/photoshop-brushes/brush-dynamics/dual-brush/ gets closer with the Dual Brushes option, but apparently that only operates where one brush constrains the other and only works with two shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Inkscape. It's free and you get vector images (which can be easily rasterized to PNG or JPG). In the left there's 5 drawn random shapes and in the right you can see what's got by selecting the symbol sprayer tool and hovering the cursor right and left a couple of seconds.

[image]

Scaling and rotating the sprayed objects are not allowed in my example as you can see in the info panel. If one wants to paint something specific with the shapes accurately scattering and the sprayer size should be reduced.

Comment: I think this looks useful, but doesn't answer their question, assuming their intent is to use Photoshop.

Comment: @SeanDuggan well, nothing will answer their question because there's no such functionality in Photoshop

Comment: One definitely true answer exists: "Become a person who programs the needed extension to Photoshop. Purchase or get otherwise the  data how to interface your code. The faster you start and get it done, the sooner you can use it!" I'm afraid this method isn't the best option for most of us.

Comment: @user287001 I wish it was possible with an extension... but it's not. I also miss this feature quite a lot but here's no api for coding new tools or modify existing tools in PS unfortunately.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy What's Adobe Photoshop SDK? I have thought it's a kit that extension programmers can purchase. I do not need it because my programming knowledge is about zero, but the name has occurred now and then a long time. It's still in Adobe's website.

Comment: @user287001 SDK is for creating plugins (mostly filters) — those are written in C++ — they can work quite fast with the all the pixels. I guess it's possible to write your own tool that'd exist inside a plugin (similar to how Liquify lives in its own window) but that's a huge hack... Extensions are a different beast — those are scripts written in JS and wrapped in HTML interface and those are found in Window > Extensions. They can only run what already exists inside PS scripting engine (ps functions + file IO) + some html goodies (download/upload, process data, etc)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy yes, but illustrator api definitely can make custom tools to do this.

Comment: @user287001 its a common misconception. But you can only bind thigs to points adobe allows you to bind